# Do I need background location in expo or is foreground location sufficient?

Tags: react-native, expo, geolocation

Working on an expo application which tracks user location just like a fitness app would. It tracks the user for a limited time (from start to finish which the user determines by clicking a button) and it is supposed to track when the phone is locked for a while as well.

Do I need to track the location in background? I wonder if I have to request permissions for background location tracking or if it works with just foreground location?

Where is the difference between the two? It seems to work with just foreground permissions when I tried, but the name suggest that I might need background tracking as well.

Comment: Foreground tracking is used when your application is in the foreground (i.e. your user has it open and is using it). Background tracking is used while your app is in the background. There used to be some overlap in the fact that you would only have to request access to tracking a user's location and you would be able to track both, but that has now changed. Source: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/#locationrequestpermissionsasync